# SQLite Merge two columns

Tags: sqlite

I've got a database with a `Country` table and it is linked with itself via a `Border` table. I want to show all the countries bordering Switzerland (CH). I've managed to do so with this:

```
SELECT B1.countryCode2, B2.countryCode1 FROM Country AS C
JOIN Border AS B1 ON B1.countryCode1 = C.code
JOIN Border AS B2 ON B2.countryCode2 = C.code
WHERE C.code = 'CH';
```

Output:

```
countryCode2  countryCode1
------------  ------------
AT            FR
DE            FR
LI            FR
AT            IT
DE            IT
LI            IT
```

but the countries are doubled since `Border` table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Border (countryCode1, countryCode2) VALUES
...
('FR', 'CH'),
...
('IT', 'CH'),
...
('CH', 'LI'),
('CH', 'DE'),
('CH', 'AT'),
...
```

Is there a way to merge the two columns and remove the duplicates?

----- Edit -----

Found solution:

```
SELECT C.name FROM Country AS C
JOIN Border AS B1 ON B1.countryCode1 = C.code
JOIN Border AS B2 ON B2.countryCode2 = C.code
WHERE B1.countryCode2 = 'CH'
OR B2.countryCode1 = 'CH'
GROUP BY C.name;
```

Comment: From the looks of it, for `all the countries bordering Switzerland (CH)`, either use `countryCode1 = 'CH'` or `countryCode2 = 'CH'`, preferably an indexed column.

Comment: Thank you very much! ```SELECT C.name FROM Country AS C
JOIN Border AS B1 ON B1.countryCode1 = C.code
JOIN Border AS B2 ON B2.countryCode2 = C.code
WHERE B1.countryCode2 = 'CH'
OR B2.countryCode1 = 'CH'
GROUP BY C.name;``` Using this it works.

Comment: Why `SELECT countryCode2 FROM Country
WHERE countryCode1 = 'CH';` doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn’t work because 'CH' is not always in first position, sometimes it is in `countryCode2`